# Ember-data mapping embedded object from JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am struggling with a strange problem. I have a model called `Activity` with a property defined like this:

`owner: DS.belongsTo('App.User', embedded: true)`

The `User` is also a defined model when I'm getting the JSON response like this:

```
some single properties and

user: { id: etc. }
```

My all properties map well but the user embedded object from JSON doesn't map to the owner property. However, when I change

```
owner
```

to

```
user
```

It maps well. But I want to leave the owner because it's a better representation of what I mean. I tried this action:

```
owner: DS.belongsTo('App.User', key: 'user', embedded: true)
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "it maps well" or "it doesn't map well"? Perhaps you could set up an example JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend using the latest Ember / EmberData, but you will need to handle embedded records manually by [enhancing `extractSingle` in a custom serializer](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records) (see example below). Also, you should define relationships like this:

```
App.Activity = DS.Model.extend({
  name:  DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name:       DS.attr('string'),
  activities: DS.hasMany('activity')
});
```

Next, I recommend using the `ActiveModelAdapter` if you are using underscores when communicating with the server (i.e. like in EmberData 0.13):

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```

Finally, to use `owner` for a `User`, override `typeForRoot` in a custom serializer.

For example:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  typeForRoot: function(root) {
    if (root == 'owner' || root == 'owners') { root = 'user'; }
    return this._super(root);
  },

  // based on: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#embedded-records
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var owner = payload.activity.owner,
        ownerId = owner.id;

    payload.owners = [owner];
    payload.activity.owner_id = ownerId;

    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

[Example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ulaVITA/1/edit?html,js,output)