# Ember data alias model / Map JSON response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My server returns a JSON response like this:

```
{
  artists: [{
    id: "1",
    first_name: "Foo",
    last_name: "Bar"
}],
  studios: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test",
    // ...
    artist_ids: ["1"]
  }]
}
```

'artist' is in fact a User model but with a different name. How can I map artist to the User model? Maybe a bad explanation but if I rename the JSON response serverside to 'users' instead of 'artist' and use the models below everything works like I want. I simply want to use the name 'artist' instead of 'user', both server side and client side. Hope you guys understand what i mean.

```
App.Studio = DS.Model.extend
  name:  DS.attr 'string'
  // ..
  users: DS.hasMany 'App.User'

App.User = DS.Model.extend
  firstName:  DS.attr 'string'
  lastName:  DS.attr 'string'
  studio: DS.belongsTo 'App.Studio'
```

I guess that the simplest thing to do would be something like **artists: DS.hasMany 'App.User'** but obviously this does not work.

Comment: You could try to serialize your data. http://ember-website.thomasboyt.com/api/data/modules/data-serializer.html

Comment: I've thought about it too but do not really understand how?

Comment: I do not have much experience with ember but take look here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6718391 `payload` should contain your server response data.

Comment: Too bad the documentation is so bad, I really do not understand what to do and that I must use Ember Data 0.13 makes it not easier. Guess this user had the same problem as me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740448/ember-data-mapping-embedded-object-from-json?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend using the latest Ember / EmberData, so relationships are defined like this:

```
App.Studio = DS.Model.extend({
  name:  DS.attr('string'),
  // ..
  users: DS.hasMany('user')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName:  DS.attr('string'),
  lastName:  DS.attr('string'),
  studio: DS.belongsTo('studio')
});
```

Next, I recommend using the `ActiveModelAdapter` if you are getting underscores in your response JSON:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter;
```

Finally, overriding `typeForRoot` and `keyForRelationship` in a custom serializer should fix your issue:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  typeForRoot: function(root) {
    if (root == 'artist' || root == 'artists') { root = 'user'; }
    return this._super(root);
  },

  keyForRelationship: function(key, kind) {
    if (key == 'users') { key = 'artists'; }
    return this._super(key, kind);
  }
});
```

[Example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UTAxIMU/3/edit?html,js,output)

One last thing: you can even get rid of the custom `keyForRelationship` if you name the relationship `artists` in `Studio`:

```
App.Studio = DS.Model.extend({
  name:  DS.attr('string'),
  // ..
  artists: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, very good answer! Unfortunately, I have to use Ember Data 0.13 because of ember auth. But I will accept this answer because it feels like this will work when I can start using the latest version of Ember Data.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just creating an Artist model extended from User?

```
App.Artist = App.User.extend({})
```

I haven't tried it, but I suspect that might work.